# Yii2 - How do standalone actions follow a defined layout

Tags: php, yii2

How do standalone actions follow a defined layout?
Inline action is quite simple, where layouts are taken from @ views/layout.

**LAYOUT**

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Url;

/* @var $this \yii\web\View */
/* @var $content string */

$favicon = Url::to('@web/img/logo.png');

app\assets\AppAsset::register($this);
app\assets\AdminLteAsset::register($this);
app\assets\AdminLtePluginAsset::register($this);
app\assets\BackendAsset::register($this);
$directoryAsset = Yii::$app->assetManager->getPublishedUrl('@vendor/almasaeed2010/adminlte/dist');
?>

<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;  charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>

    <?php $this->registerLinkTag(['rel' => 'icon', 'type' => 'image/png', 'href' => "$favicon"]); ?>
    <title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>

    <?php $this->head() ?>

</head>
<body class="hold-transition <?= \dmstr\helpers\AdminLteHelper::skinClass() ?> sidebar-mini fixed">
<div class="se-pre-con"></div>
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>
<div class="wrapper">

    <?=
    $this->render(
        'header.php', ['directoryAsset' => $directoryAsset]
    )
    ?>

    <?=
    $this->render(
        'left.php', ['directoryAsset' => $directoryAsset]
    )
    ?>

    <?=
    $this->render(
        'content.php', ['content' => $content, 'directoryAsset' => $directoryAsset]
    )
    ?>

</div>

<?php $this->endBody() ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
class BillOfLadingController extends Controller{

    public function actionIndex(){
        $searchModel = new BillOfLadingSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**convert to standalone action**

```
class BillOfLadingController extends Controller{

    public function actions(){
        $searchModel = new BillOfLadingSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return [
            'index' => [
                'class' => 'app\common\actions\admin\billOfLading\indexAction',
                'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'layout' => $this->layout
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Then in class `app\common\actions\admin\billOfLading\indexAction`,
I use a widget as a view

When the controller code above is changed to use standalone action,

```
<?php
namespace app\common\actions\admin\billOfLading;

use app\common\widgets\admin\billOfLading\BillOfLadingWidget;
use yii\base\Action;

class indexAction extends Action
{
    public $searchModel;
    public $dataProvider;

    public function run()
    {
        try {
            return
                BillOfLadingWidget::widget([
                    'searchModel' => (object)$this->searchModel,
                    'dataProvider' => (object)$this->dataProvider,
                ]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}
```

**WIDGET**

```
<?php

namespace app\common\widgets\admin\billOfLading;

use yii\base\Widget;

class BillOfLadingWidget extends Widget
{

    public $searchModel;
    public $dataProvider;

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
    }


    public function run()
    {
        return $this->render('index', [
            'dataProvider' => $this->dataProvider,
            'searchModel' => $this->searchModel
        ]);
    }

    public function getViewPath()
    {
        return '@app/common/widgets/admin/billOfLading/views/';
    }
}
```

Layout does not work.
There is only the display of the widget.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am not sure what requirements forced you to extend the `yii\base\Action` class instead of extending the `yii\web\ViewAction` class.

But, if still, you want to do it this way you might need to declare a property `$layout` inside your `indexAction` because `$layout` isn't the part of the `yii\base\Action` class, neither you have defined inside your custom `IndexAction`.

Then you have to add the layout code the similar way as it is done in the [`yii\web\ViewAction`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/ViewAction.php#L66) class

```
<?php
namespace app\common\actions\admin\billOfLading;

use app\common\widgets\admin\billOfLading\BillOfLadingWidget;
use yii\base\Action;

class indexAction extends Action
{
    public $searchModel;
    public $dataProvider;
    public $layout;

    public function run()
    {
        //set the controller layout
        $controllerLayout = null;
        if ($this->layout !== null) {
            $controllerLayout = $this->controller->layout;
            $this->controller->layout = $this->layout;
        }
        try {
            if ($controllerLayout) {
                $this->controller->layout = $controllerLayout;
            }
            return
                BillOfLadingWidget::widget(
                    [
                        'searchModel' => (object)$this->searchModel,
                        'dataProvider' => (object)$this->dataProvider,
                    ]
                );
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}
```

Now your Standalone action will apply the layout.